# Replace symbol if it is preceded and followed by a word character

Tags: php, preg-replace, replace

I want to change a specific character, only if it's previous and following character is of English characters. In other words, the target character is part of the word and not a start or end character.

For Example...

```
$string = "I am learn*ing *PHP today*";
```

I want this string to be converted as following.

```
$newString = "I am learn'ing *PHP today*";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = "I am learn*ing *PHP today*";
$newString = preg_replace('/(\w)\*(\w)/', '$1\'$2', $string);

// $newString = "I am learn'ing *PHP today* "
```

This will match an asterisk surrounded by word characters (letters, digits, underscores). If you only want to do alphabet characters you can do:

```
preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z])\*([a-zA-Z])/', '$1\'$2', 'I am learn*ing *PHP today*');
```

Comment: This replaces only first occurance. How about for a string like  "I am learn*ing PHP to*day";

Comment: Although it might be worth mentioning how to replace only the first, as OP's example replaces only the first.

Comment: Thanks for the question edit, marcog. Makes things clearer. OP is asking to replace **all** occurrences of `asterisk surrounded by letters`.

Comment: @webbiedave - Thanks for the answer. It works in PHP very well. Just out of curiosity, what if I wanted to replace all asteric from the string if they are at (start AND end of the word) or just in the middle of word. i.e. to replace $string = "I am *learn*ing* *php today* with gre*at j*oy"; into $string = "I am 'learn'ing' *php today* with gre'at jo'y"; Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean... from "I am *learn*ing* php today with gre*at j*oy" to "I am 'learn'ing' php today with gre'at jo'y"

Comment: there are asterics at the start and end of the word "learning" but somehow, it doesn't get printed in last two comment. sorry

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way would be to use "word boundary" characters in your pattern -- they represent a zero-width position between a "word" character and a "non-word" characters.  Since `*` is a non-word character, the word boundaries require the both neighboring characters to be word characters.

No capture groups, no references.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dJuS0))

```
$string = "I am learn*ing *PHP today*";
echo preg_replace('~\b\*\b~', "'", $string);
```

Output:

```
I am learn'ing *PHP today*
```

Answer (score -1):

To replace only alphabetical characters, you need to use a [a-z] as a character range, and use the i flag to make the regex case-insensitive. Since the character you want to replace is an asterisk, you also need to escape it with a backslash, because an asterisk means "match zero or more times" in a regular expression.

```
$newstring = preg_replace('/([a-z])\*([a-z])/i', "$1'$2", $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

To replace all occurances of asteric surrounded by letter....

$string = preg_replace('/(\w)*(\w)/', '$1\'$2', $string);

AND

To replace all occurances of asteric where asteric is start and end character of the word....

$string = preg_replace('/*(\w+)*/','\'$1\'', $string);